# How can I do this in Jade?

Tags: express, pug

I'm trying to translate this in my jade template but can't. Any help?

```
<span class="riciclame_piccolo">
   ricicla
   <span class="rosa">
      .me
   </span>
</span>
<span class="footer_p"> 
   &nbsp&nbsp è un'idea di <a href="http://www.ottoquattro.com" target="_blank">OttoQuattro Web & Video Agency</a>
</span>
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Something like this...

```
span.riciclame_piccolo ricicla
    span.rosa .me
span.footer_p &nbsp&nbsp è un'idea di 
    a(href="http://www.ottoquattro.com", target="_blank") OttoQuattro Web & Video Agency​
```